# android, xhdpi - heap

Tags: android, image, memory, memory-management, drawable

I have 15 images in drawable-xhdpi, each is 800x800, in drawable-hdpi I have the same images but 600x600, when I run the application on the device with hdpi resolution the heap size is about 3mb, but when I run it on device with xhdpi resolution the heap size is over 40mb and I get outofmemory?
What is wrong? Are images too large?

heap size:
ldpi : ~3mb
mdpi : ~3mb
hdpi : ~3mb
xhdpi : ~40mb

Load image in this way:

```
 b1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.image);
 imageview.setImageBitmap(b1);

then in OnBackPressed() b1.recycle()
```

Comment: Could you use `imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.image)` instead?  That way you shouldn't have to worry about recycling bitmaps.

Comment: I'm guessing that you will need to share more about your app (what are you doing with these images, how many are showing at a time, etc.) and probably some more code to get any further.  Unless what you have shown thus far is really all you are doing?

Comment: There are 15 images *.png (transparent) and each image is located on previous image, it's sth like a stack. When I click on image I change the visibilty to gone. That's all ;) each xhdpi file is 80kB, hdpi: 60kB

Comment: did u find any solution... im facing same issue in my app too...
also u may like to reduce the png size dramatically using this online tool...
http://tinypng.org/

Answer (score 5):

This has been asked many times before... The real memory used for a bitmap when loaded is `H x W x 4`. 800 * 800 * 4 * 15 = 38 MB. You should never load all 15 images at the same time. Since they are about the size of the screen, resampling doesn't make sense in this case, you just have to figure out how to get around not loading all of them at the same time.

Comment: I need to load them in the same time. What about svg?

Comment: Well, ya can't :) . How about combining them into the end result that you want?